# Array values to variable

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with extracting values from an array. `print_r($offers);` output is as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Object
        (
            [id] => 41302512
            [amount] => 244
            [price] => 10.17
            [sellerId] => 1678289
            [sellerName] => stan_J23
        )
    [1] => Object
        (
            [id] => 41297403
            [amount] => 51
            [price] => 10.18
            [sellerId] => 2510426
            [sellerName] => kszonek1380
        )
    [2] => Object
        (
            [id] => 41297337
            [amount] => 581
            [price] => 10.18
            [sellerId] => 2863620
            [sellerName] => NYski
        )
)
```

However, `echo $offers[0]['id'];` doesn't work. I need to extract the values for each array node to variables i.e. `$id=value_of_key_id` and so on. The array has 10 nodes from 0 to 9.

Comment: `[0]` is an object, not an array. So do `$offers[0]->id`

Comment: That's because `$offers[0]` is an Object, not an array. Use `$offers[0]->id`

Answer (score 2):

Try `echo $offer[0]->{'id'}`.

It says it's an object, and you need to get the 'id' key in that way with objects.

See Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Why `->{'id'}` and not just `->id`?

Comment: I've kind of forced myself to always use curly brackets, so that it always works; but you're right: it's unnecessary in this case. @pduersteler

Comment: `echo $offers[0]->id;` works. The only left is how to loop from 0 to 9.

Comment: just hadn't seen that syntax before, so I had to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$offers is an array of objects, not array. You will need to access the elements via `$offers[0]->id;` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, working code is:

```
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
$id = $offer->id;
$amount = $offer->amount;
$price = $offer->price;
$sellerId = $offer->sellerId;
$sellerName = $offer->sellerName;
echo "$id<br />$amount<br />$price<br />$sellerId<br />$sellerName<br /><hr /><br />";
}
```